# Can't connect to Chrome app tcp server through from outside my local network

Tags: google-chrome-app, tcpserver, listen

I didn't manage to access fron internet to a chrome app tcp server.
firewall and home network well configured, I tried and managed with a native c++ tcp server through the same port.

My manifest is like that:

```
"sockets": {
    "tcpServer": {
        "listen": "*"
    }
}
```

and my tcpServer is launched like that:

```
// ...
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({name:"chrome-local-tcp-server", persistent:false}, function(createInfo) {
    _this.info = createInfo;

    // Listening TCP server
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(createInfo.socketId, "127.0.0.1", 8000, null, function(result) {
        // ...
    });
}):
```

Only localhost client connection work

---

```
function WebSocketServer(port)
{
    this.port = port;
    this.ips = [];
    this.ip_serverInfo = {};
    this.webSockets = [];
    this.socketId_webSocket = {};

    var _this = this;

    chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function(interfaces) {
        interfaces.forEach(openSocket);
    });

    function openSocket(interface) {
        chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create({name:"chrome-local-tcp-server", persistent:false}, function(createInfo) {
            _this.ips.push(interface.address);
            _this.ip_serverInfo[interface.address] = createInfo;

            chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(createInfo.socketId, interface.address, port, null, function(resultCode) {
                if (resultCode < 0)
                {
                    console.log("Error listening: "+chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("tcpServer listenning on "+interface.address+":"+port, createInfo);
                }
            });
        });
    }

    // New connection
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.onAccept.addListener(function(info) {
        debug && console.log("tcpSocket accepted", info);
        var ws = new WebSocket(info);
        _this.webSockets.push(ws);
        _this.socketId_webSocket[info.clientSocketId] = ws;
        ws.closeTcpSocket = function(clientInfo) {
            // close TCP connection
            chrome.sockets.tcp.disconnect(clientInfo.clientSocketId, function() {
                chrome.sockets.tcp.close(clientInfo.clientSocketId, function() {
                    console.log("tcpSocket closed", clientInfo);
                    delete _this.socketId_webSocket[clientInfo.clientSocketId];
                    arrayRemoveValue(_this.webSockets, ws);
                });
            });
        };
    });

    // Connection error
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.onAcceptError.addListener(function(info) {
        console.error("tcpServer onAcceptError", info);
    }); 

    // on received data
    chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(function(info) {
        //console.log("onReceive", info);
        var ws = _this.socketId_webSocket[info.socketId];
        if (ws)
        {
            ws.tcpDataReceived(info.data);
        }
    });

    // on received error
    chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError.addListener(function(info) {
        if (info.resultCode !== -15)
        {
            console.error("tcp socket onReceiveError", info);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please state which host OS you're using.

Comment: Windows 7 x64, but I want to allow users to listen from any ip address in any OS. Anyway do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found. I had to open the port in my windows firewall. That's not done automatically for this Chrome feature !

Answer (score 4):

You must understand what the "address" parameter of opening a server socket does. Sockets only listen to connections on a particular interface, represented by the network address.

In your manifest, you **allowed** your app to bind the socket to any interface with `"listen": "*"`.

However, inn this line:

```js
chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(createInfo.socketId, "127.0.0.1", 8000, null, function(result) {
    // ...
});
```

You explicitly **bind your socket** to the address 127.0.0.1, which is a local-only interface. No other machine can connect to your machine through this address.

If you look at various Chrome app samles [like this one](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/chrome-app-samples/tree/master/samples/tcpserver), they feature interface selection. From looking at Chrome source, e.g. [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/net/socket/server_socket.cc&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=19&rcl=1414441904), it seems like API does not allow to bind to "any interface" like `INADDR_ANY` can.

So, you need to gather available interfaces with [`chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/system_network#method-getNetworkInterfaces), and either let the user choose, try to guess the appropriate interface, or just create a socket per every interface.

---

Apparently this needs further explanation. An open socket that listens to connections is bound to a certain network interface. A computer can have several interfaces, and as a consequence several IP addresses.

`127.0.0.1` is a special network interface that only works locally. You need to bind to your machine's address (say, `192.168.1.2`) to receive external connections. You **don't need to know** the IP of the person connecting, and not even your "external IP" if you're behind a port-forwarding router - only **the address of your network card**.

You can get all addresses assigned to your machine by declaring `"system.network"` permission and calling `chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces()`:

```js
chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function(interfaces) {
  interfaces.forEach(function(interface) {
    console.log(interface);
  });
});
```

This will list all network interfaces. You either need to select one (by presenting a choice to the user, or somehow selecting one yourself) or you can **bind a socket per interface** to listen on them all. Here's an example of how it can be done:

```js
chrome.system.network.getNetworkInterfaces(function(interfaces) {
  interfaces.forEach(openSocket);
});

function openSocket(interface) {
  chrome.sockets.tcpServer.create(
    {name:"chrome-local-tcp-server", persistent:false},
    function(createInfo) {
      _this.info = createInfo;

    // Listening TCP server
    chrome.sockets.tcpServer.listen(
      createInfo.socketId,
      interface.address, 8000, null,
      function(result) {
        // ...
      }
    );
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there really no solution to listen to any address? I can't use NPAPI plugins because of deprecated method. What are my solutions? I don't know the ip addresses of people who want to connect to this embedded tcp server.

Comment: You misunderstand. You bind a socket to a _local_ address, not the _remote_ address of a connecting client. I will expand the answer when I have the time today.

Comment: Okay very interesting, thank you. But I can't connect to the tcp server from another computer (even in the same local network). I updated the first post with the new code. Am I doing another thing wrong?

Comment: Your code seems to somehow mix and match raw sockets and WebSockets. What are you trying to achieve? `new WebSocket(info)` seems highly suspect too.

Comment: I implemented a websocket server in a chrome app. It works in localhost. But I don't understand why I can't connect from another computer? I listen through the interfaces like you suggested without success.

Comment: Do you have an idea why I can't connect to the tcp server with another computer?

Comment: I tried to use chrome.system.network.getInterfaces but I have this error : "Could not get network interfaces".  I am trying this for Cordova.